# How can I select specific sections of an image to determine RGB values using R?

Tags: r, image, rgb

I use R for my stats analyses and I am trying to use it as well to do some image analyze. I am not an expert in coding or R, but I am trying to learn more. So sorry if my question could sound basic.
I am doing some staining to potato slices, the staining turns my potato slices dark brown in the parts where is the compound I want to see. So I used package "jpeg" and "lessR" [This image is what I get using this package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKLQo.jpg) so I could have a section of my image analyze to get the RGB values. But I just can make a rectangular section, and like that, I lose parts of my stained image. Is there a way where I can "tell" R to analyze all the slice? My background is whitish.[example of one my images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMsLa.jpg)
Thank you in advance.

Claudia

Comment: Welcome to stack. It would be great that you give what you achieved, and a reproducible example with the desired result. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you will find [imageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) more useful for image analysis. This can give you some raw data that you can then use R on.

Comment: Hi @bob1 I had try that way, but it takes much time, because you need 1st to select slice by slice and do the histogram for each slice and put all that data in excel and after run all that in R. Like I have so many samples to analyse I would like a faster method. And using the packages "jpeg" and "lessR" is faster but I cannot analyse all the slice just the central part of it.

Comment: Hi @denis I add a new image to show what I get using the packages I am using in R, and the end result is an excel file with the RGB values. This is part of what I got for the attached image (not enough space to put all) :                                                                   
     Colour mid edge background
1 red 95.64040122 88.60964995 146.8688606
2 red 107.8587568 96.53139274 157.7072124
3 red 96.48107518 75.34172801 167.7170019

Comment: @Claudia, I would look into recording a macro and then using it for batch processing in imageJ - you don't need to do this for each image separately, just start recording and then do all steps for one image, stop recording, then apply that to all images in a folder. Also note that `.jpg` images are not great for image analysis because of the method of compression that they use, which converts all similar pixels in an area into the same value, you are much better off (scientifically!) using `.tif` files.

Comment: Hi @bob1, thank you for your comment, I will try what you say.